# onPress for listview in react-native does not work

Tags: facebook, react-native

I'm facing a weird problem. In my react native app, if I set onPress event to Button it is not triggered. What am I missing here?

```
import React, {Component,} from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Image, ListView, StyleSheet, Text, View,} from 'react-native';

   var REQUEST_URL ='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/react-native/master/docs/MoviesExample.json'; //URL to fetch json data

   export default class SampleAppMovies extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       dataSource: new ListView.DataSource({
       rowHasChanged: (row1, row2) => row1 !== row2,
      }),
      loaded: false,
    };
  }

//Before Page view 
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
}

//Fetch Data
fetchData() {
  fetch(REQUEST_URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseData) => {
          this.setState({
            dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(responseData.movies),
            loaded: true,
          });
       })
       .done();
   }
  //On press for get all data 
 _getData = (name) =>{
     console.log(name); 
  }
 //On Press for getmovie
 _getMovie=(movie)=>{
     console.log('Movie Name', movie.title); //To get movie title
     console.log('Movie Year', movie.year); //To get movie year
  }
 //Main render view
 render() {
  if (!this.state.loaded) {
    return this.renderLoadingView();
  }
   //List View
   return (
      <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={this.renderMovie}
       /> //List view
    );
  }
  renderLoadingView() {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>//Before loading all movies list
            Loading movies...
          </Text>
         </View>
     );
   }
  //To get view movie list
  renderMovie(movie) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}}
           style={styles.thumbnail}
         /> //Image of movie
        <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
          <Button transparent onPress={this._getData(movie)}>  //Onpress to get all details
            <Text style={styles.title} >{movie.title}</Text>
          </Button>
          <Button transparent onPress={this._getMovie(movie)}>// On Press
            <Text style={styles.year} >{movie.year}</Text>
          </Button>
        </View>
      </View>
     );
   }
 }
```

Is there any solution to get onpress trigger for above example without adding onPress on ListView tag?

Comment: Try adding one of your `onPress` functions to the root `<View>` as a first debugging step.

Comment: you are actually CALLING the function right away and setting `onPress` equal to the value that your function returns. If uou want `onPress` to be an actual function, not its return value (makes the most sense) then follow the answer below or set `onPress={this._getMovie}` but then you dont have the ability to pass in the `movie` variable you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your onPress with:

```
<Button title={movie.year} onPress={() => {
  this._getMovie(movie)
}}/>
```

Comment: What he has there should be fine.